# How to implement "del" function in struts2-jquery-grid?

Tags: jquery, eclipse, postgresql, struts2, java-ee-6

I´m try to implement a system using struts2-jquery-grid. It´s almost working. The grid is loaded with "add" and "edit" functions, but "del" does not work. I tried a lot of codes but didn´t get it.

Here is the action´s snippet where i try to del some register of database:

```
    else if (oper.equalsIgnoreCase("del")){
        concurso = new Concurso();
        String sql = "delete from dpp.concurso where idconcurso=?";

        try {
            ConcursoDAO.encontrarIdconcurso(idconcurso);
            concurso.setIdconcurso(idconcurso);

            PreparedStatement stmt = this.connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setLong(1, concurso.getIdconcurso());
        stmt.execute();
        stmt.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

It´s obvious, idconcurso is null. but, how can I pass a parameter to use it for delete???

Thank´s

Comment: how you are passing that parameter can you show that code?

Comment: I´m not passing. I tried with the code of the post. But it doesn´t work.
It´s exactly what I want to know. How to pass some parameter?

Comment: what you mean by passing parameter.

Comment: I want to delete something in the database. So, I need to pass some parameter for it to delete. The code described don´t get it. So, I want to pass something, like an id or code where the database gets it and delete the register.

Comment: Please partition the problem, as it stands no one can help you... struts2 handles the front end, what you have shown has nothing to do with struts2. Can you make a simple test which deletes an entry from the database? It the database being issued a delete (can you check the DB logs)?

Comment: Quaternion, i am showing the snippet of execute() in the action. I didn´t post all the code, because only the "del" function doesn´t work, because i am using struts2-jquery-grid. In a simple form, the code works. If you want, i can post the complete action and jsp.

Answer (score 1):

I had also faced similar issue and solve the problem by setting key attribute true for id field. So you could use attribute key="true" for column "idconcurso" at jquery gridview  in your jsp page. Like:

```
<sjg:gridColumn name="progId" key="true" index="progId" editable="true" hidden="true" title="Project ID" />
```

Since your id column is non-editable so you could make it as hidden.

One more thing you need to define property id and it's getter and setter method in struts action  class and from id property you could get the "idconcurso" value.